# Can't delete empty space at the end of Sony Vegas file

Tags: video-editing, sony-vegas

I'm having a problem with extra video at the end of my edits. I have this huge empty space that has no video or audio, but I can't delete it. Right now my method of getting rid of it is to open it in Windows Live Movie Maker, then trim the extra out and render it. But it would save me a lot of time if I could just do it in Pro. Anyone know how?

Comment: I actually figured it out myself through a lot of youtube networking. Either set the playback loop, the little yellow triangles at the top, at the beggining and end of your clip, or uncheck the "allow playback loop" box when designating where to render the file to.

Comment: Please put this as a real answer below and mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 2):

Either set the playback loop, the little yellow triangles at the top, at the beginning and end of your clip, or uncheck the "allow playback loop" box when designating where to render the file to.